# PHP MySQL Table, Using to log into account in the table

Tags: php, mysql

I have got a MySQL Table named 'MainData' and i have 3 columns 'username', 'email' and 'pass'. I have a snipped of my code, it all works except when i try to convert the users $_POST input into an md5 hash. When i leave the md5 encryption's off and all of the passwords are visible in the database it works but when i use md5 it doesnt work and just echo's 'Sorry, the username or password was incorrect.' 
Here is the snipped of my code:

```
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "avxtechn_benph64";
$password = "admin123";
$dbname = "avxtechn_users";
$dbtable = "MainData";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$usr = $_POST["user"];
$psr = $_POST["password"];

$sql = "SELECT username, pass FROM " . $dbtable;
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$nameCount = 0;
$UserName = 0;
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ( $usr == $row["username"] && md5($psr) == $row["pass"]) {
            $nameCount = $nameCount + 1;
            $UserName = $usr;
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "nil";
}
if ($nameCount > 0) {
    echo ' Welcome back, ' . $UserName;
}else{
    echo 'Sorry, that username or password was incorrect.';
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

This is the full code.

Here is the PHPMyAdmin database:
[image]

Comment: You shouldn't use `md5`. Use [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

Comment: ... For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: *"but when i use md5 it doesnt work"* - Call it a blessing in disguise.

Comment: What does your sql look like? Using a `while` loop seems a bit strange to authenticate a user...

Comment: So, were the passwords initially saved as MD5?

Comment: what is the length of your password ? some times it may be truncated as the hash will be legthy

Comment: All comments above being ignored?

Comment: Sorry didnt see all of these

Comment: Im new to all of this PHP stuff aswell

Comment: Yes they are saved as md5, ignore the ben hirst one that was an error and i dont use that

Comment: Well, check to see if your form's a POST method and that all elements hold a name attribute. Error reporting will tell you if there are errors. However, I wouldn't spend too much time on this. MD5 is unsafe to use for passwords. There are plenty of ready made scripts out there using safer methods.

Comment: Yes, it is a POST method, it all works if i dont use the md5 when checking if the user's input is the same as in the database

Comment: Try adding a `where` clause to your query then.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your problem is you stored passwords in your database before as a plain text.

So to get your authentification work now you should:

```
if ( $usr == $row["username"] && $psr == $row["pass"]) {
```

or

```
if ( $usr == $row["username"] && (md5($psr)) == md5($row["pass"])) {
```

but the best way is to convert your data (make backup first for sure) by running this query:

```
UPDATE MainData SET pass = MD5(pass)
```

then your code can start to work. but check the `pass` type before converting to assure that it can hold larger strings.

Comment: So i am trying to convert the user's input to match the data in the MySQL Table

Comment: Show the full code fragment then. What is your query? what is your table structure? what is your data to debug?  how was insert done?

Comment: @BenHirst seems your column size is smaller than you need

Comment: Yes, i have realised that, i have now fixed the error, thank you for all the help. I have used password_hash and verify instead of md5.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend to change your code.
Use the following SQL code:
`$result = $conn->query('SELECT count(*) as nr WHERE username = ' . $username . ' AND pass = MD5('. $password .'));`

You should have an integer of 1 in "nr" if the login is valid.
Make Mysql do a single count of the usernames having that user/password combination.

Also MySQL is able to do the MD5 method for you.
( Instead of looping all the results in your resultset. )

EDIT:
Please sanitize your input before adding it into queries.